# Batch File: syntax is incorrect while setting variables

Tags: batch-file, gnupg

I am getting syntax error while seting variables .  Can some one please tell me where i am doing wrong.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
cd C:\data
for %%i in (*.pgp)
 do 
(
set encrypted=%%i
    set decrypted=!encrypted:.gpg=!
    gpg --batch --yes --passphrase "xyz" -o !decrypted! --decrypt !encrypted!
)
endlocal
```

if i do the same logic with out seting any variables it works

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%i in (*.pgp)
 do 
(
```

must be coded as

```
for %%i in (*.pgp) do (
```

ie. the `do` and the `)` and the `(` after the `do` must all be on the same physical line.

Also, in your replace `set`, have you specified `.gpg` in place of `.pgp`?? (in which case, `%%~ni` could be used in place of the substitution.

in the `gpg` line, perhaps you need to quote the decrypted and encrypted strings, or you could possibly use "`%%~ni`" and "`%%i`" respectively.